# Unbind not doing what it should

Tags: javascript, unbind, jquery-1.4

I must be missing something fundamental, but for the life of me cant work it out.

the idea is when u click that click event is then unbind. Also to note the alert('test') is not firing.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#menu .cat-item a').each( function() {
    $(this).bind('click',hide).unbind('click',hide);
  });
 });


 function hide(){
   alert('test')
    $("#home-content").fadeIn();
   $("#home-page").fadeOut();
 }
```

Using jquery 1.4

Many Thanks

Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since jQuery supports a fluent programming style `bind` actually returns the `this` object.

So in this case you are first adding the handler and then **immediately** removing it.

The correct version is

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#menu .cat-item a').each( function() {
         $(this).bind('click',hide);
    });
});


function hide(){
    $(this).unbind('click',hide);
    $("#home-content").fadeIn();
    $("#home-page").fadeOut();
}
```

Comment: yep thats the one. Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are unbinding immediately after you bind! You'll need to unbind within the handler (`hide`) to ensure that it's executed, otherwise you might consider this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#menu .cat-item a').one("click", hide);
});
```

[`one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) will ensure that a handler is only executed *once* per element.